# How to download an image to android device from azure blob using c# and Xamarin

Tags: android, c#-4.0, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

I want to store an Image from Azure blob to android device. I am using Xamarin, C# to develop the android app.
 I am able to save the file in my local system when testing but when i deploy the code to mobile the file is not getting saved in device.

```
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("blob");
foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
            {
               if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob pageBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    pageBlob.DownloadToFile(documentsPath+"inage.jpg",FileMode.Create);
                    //pageBlob.DownloadToByteArray(documentsPath + @"\inage.jpg", FileMode.);


                }
            }
```

Comment: Did you get any exception? 
Did you notice typo in "inage,jpg"?
Try to save some text file to Personal folder, may be you have no access for writing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using Azure Mobile?  If so, there's a built-in feature for blob storage, but it's in the newer service, Azure Mobile Apps. I'm from the product team, and we recommend that new projects use Azure Mobile Apps instead of Mobile Services. For more information, see [I use Mobile Services, how does App Service help?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-value-prop-migration-from-mobile-services/).

Here's a tutorial on how to do this in Xamarin.Forms: [Connect to Azure Storage in your Xamarin.Forms app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/).